# Wix Background video on the banner of the Home page - Fails to play in Iphone on Low battery Mode

Tags: iphone

I am building a wix website using wix editor, there is a background video on the banner of the home page and this video doesn't play in Iphone when the battery is in low power mode. Is there a way to force it, I have no website coding background but will be interested to know and see it if someone has done it before? Thank you.